# Google Chrome cannot be started automatically

Tags: windows, google-chrome, boot

When I try to put Google Chrome in the Windows (Vista 64) startup folder, the browser launches with a blank page and then stops responding. Manually launching Chrome works perfectly well.
What is causing this and - more importantly - how can it be fixed?

Comment: There's an open bug that looks very similar: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5987

Comment: Are you copying the EXE there or placing a shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

Add the shortcut to the startup folder.  Alternatively you can add chrome via scheduled tasks. (control panel)